# Jenkins Publish Over SSH server password changed overtime

Tags: jenkins, ssh, ssh-keys

currently I'm using password authentication for connecting to the server.
 However, my company policy forces the password to be newly generated upon new access.
I don't want to change the configuration every time.
How can I configure this with the Publish Over SSH plugin?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can have password of any one Unix like machine as constant then you can route through others why shell script.

this intermediate machine then can connect with public and private key to the server machines.

I'm sure there could be a better answer though.